# DirectAccess Setup on a Home ISP

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, internet, windows-server-2012-r2, direct-access

I have a home office and I would like to setup DirectAccess from WS2012R2 for the client so their laptops are always able to VPN and connect home to access files and more.

From the ISP side I've heard you need 2 IPv4 static addresses for DA to work. Is that true? I've always been under the impression you only need 1 for the IPv6 tunnel thru IPv4 for DA to be usable.

Also, are their any minimum requirements as far as internet speed for optimal results?

Comment: Wouldn't you like some nice native IPv6 right about now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637797(v=ws.10).aspx (Windows Server 2008 R2):

> On the DirectAccess server, at least two consecutive, public IPv4 addresses assigned to the network adapter that is connected to the Internet.

According to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574101.aspx (Windows Server 2012 / 2012 R2):

> Configure the following:
>
> ◦ One static public IPv4 address with the appropriate subnet masks.
>
> ◦ A default gateway IPv4 address of your Internet firewall or local Internet service provider (ISP) router.